# Continuity of the Convolution of Functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convolution

I have a question that I have seen a lot on this site but always with Lebesgue Theory, which I have not learned so I get kinda confused by all the notation and am looking for a easier more straightforward solution. The question is:

> Suppose $g$ is any integrable function which need not be continuous or differentiable. Suppose $f$ is a smooth function with derivatives of all orders on $\mathbb R$. Show that $(f*g)(x)\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$, or in other words, continuous and differentiable in all orders. Does $f$ have compact support?

Now, I firstly try to show continuity. I wrote as $y\rightarrow z$, we need
$|f*g(z)-f*g(y)|\rightarrow 0$. The way I tried to solve this is by showing:
$$|f*g(z)-f*g(y)| = \left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z-x)\cdot g(x)-f(y-x)\cdot g(x) dx\right| = \left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(z-x)-f(y-x))\cdot g(x) dx\right|$$
$g$ is integrable, thus must have a supremum, and so we get:
$$|f*g(z)-f*g(y)| \leq ||g(x)||_{\infty}\cdot\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(z-x)-f(y-x)|dx$$
Now the integrand above will tend to $0$ as $y\rightarrow z$ because of the continuity of $f$ no?
Also, was wondering if a bounded function required compact support? Picturing it in my head, it does seem to make sense, but I was wondering if it was mandatory. If anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is likely to be very hard to prove without Lebesgue integration because Riemann integration has very bad convergence properties.

Comment: Our Professor has never mentioned anything about Lebesgue so I'm assuming he's expecting us to do this question without any Lebesgue in mind. @Ian

Comment: In principle you'll need to use some result about interchange of limit and integral (so that you can write $(f*g)'=f'*g$), and those are very limited in the Riemann setting.